# Druid - lookups

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

i have troubles with creating lookups in druid. I want to create lookup with a csv , and the main issue is to map multiple url's to one "group", for example :

csv file content:

```
page.href, hrefsGroup
https://google.com, search
https://yahoo.com, search
https://medium.com, informations
https://wikipedia, informations
```

And I want to create query that return's response similar to:

```
[
 { value: 'search', pv: '2354321' },
 { value: 'informations', pv: '82183123' }
]
```

FYI: `pv` is a metric `{ type: 'numeric', metric: 'count' }`

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a simple TopN query -

```
{"queryType":"topN","dataSource":"wikiticker","intervals":["2016-06-27/2016-06-28"],"granularity":"all","dimension":"hrefsGroup","metric":"pv","threshold":25,"aggregations":[{"type":"longSum","name":"pv","fieldName":"count"}]}
```

It will list top 25 hrefsGroups along with there pageview sums.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not work. Result of this query is :

`{
                "pv": 0,
                "hrefsGroup": null
            }`

Comment: I hope you had updated the datasource and time interval values as per your case. Share the complete query and druid segment details.

Comment: that's query:
`{
   "queryType":"topN",
   "dataSource":"my_datasource_that_i can_share",
   "intervals":[
      "2017-01-27/2018-06-28"
   ],
   "granularity":"all",
   "dimension": {
    "type": "lookup",
    "dimension": "data.page.href",
    "outputName": "value",
    "name": "hrefMerges"
   },
   "metric":"pv",
   "threshold":1000,
   "aggregations":[
      {
         "type":"longSum",
         "name":"pv",
         "fieldName":"count"
      }
   ]
}`

but i don't have permissions to see druid segment details :(

Comment: query seems fine, you need to check in druid logs to see whats the issue, or atleast get details on the segments.

Comment: That's was strange , but I just add `{ "isOneToMany": true }` in to lookup configuration and thats starts work :)